# alert in page does not appear when loaded through window.history.back()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have

```
 $(document).ready(function(){alert('Page-A');});
```

in page A.
It works perectly fine, except when I go to some page B and come back to page A using

```
 window.history.back();
```

Why does this happen and how do I fix this?

I forgot to mention, this problem occurs only in mobilephone browsers.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: because the page was already loaded.. and `ready` was not called

Comment: see my answer below, it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your previous page (the page which is shown when you do a browser back or history.back()), add the following javascript line of code in the `<script>` tag in `<head>` section of the page:

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(e){};
```

When you attach the onbeforeunload handler, then when you visit the same page via browsers history navigation, the scripts on the page still execute.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `window.history.go(-1);`